# Using ProgressDialog in android application startup

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

How can I show a progressDialog during the start up of an application. I have shown a progressDialog in the oncreate method and its not showing when launching the application.

I have gone through this:
[ProgressDialog not showing until after function finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533308/progressdialog-not-showing-until-after-function-finishes)

I have tried the solution explained for the above question. But its not working perfectly.

**Here is my code:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.dash);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

        //Run background UI thread
        Thread laucherThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {            
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //I had to include this to prevent force close error
                startService(new Intent(DroidChirp.this,ChirpService.class));
                doBindService();
                Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Prepairing to close the dialog");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                    
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Closed the dialog");
            }
         });
        laucherThread.start();
    }
```

**What I need to do is**:

- Show a progressDialog until all the initial setup is finished

**Issues I am facing** :

- ProgressDialog is not showing at the start up.
- There is a delay when starting the application(Showing blank for sometime).
- ProgressDialog appears just before finishing the initial setup.

Can anyone suggest me how can I establish this feature. Its a tablelayout with list view for each tab.

Comment: why do you need ProgressDialog here . You are not doing any background operation here. you don't need ProgressDialog to start a service.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get u! My dashboard is created when the service connects. A few methods are running under service to get the initial data. I m using activity based tab for my tablayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a progress dialog, while fetching data or something like this, you need to use `AsyncTask` with `ProgressDialog` bounded. See an example [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).