# Android Programming: I cannot get data from a background thread AND show a progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

Sorry, the title is a bit hard to understand but I'm not 100% sure as to what to ask. its easier to show you the code and see if you understand from that. I found the way to use the progress dialog from another post on here, so this is basically adding onto that post. ( [ProgressDialog not showing until after function finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533308/progressdialog-not-showing-until-after-function-finishes) )
btw, this is using eclipse environment with the android plugin.

```
            final MyClass mc = new MyClass(text,info, this);
            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {            
                public void run() 
                {
                    // keep sure that this operations
                    // are thread-safe!
                    Looper.prepare(); //I had to include this to prevent force close error

                    mc.doStuff();//does ALOT of stuff and takes about 30 seconds to complete... which is why i want it in a seperate thread

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {                    
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(dialog.isShowing())
                                dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            t.start();

            tmp = mc.getStuff();
```

now the issue is that tmp is always null because mc isnt finished doing stuff. So, if i do this it finishes doing stuff, but doesnt show the progress dialog..

```
            t.start();
            while(t.isAlive());//noop
            tmp = mc.getStuff();
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use AsyncTask for this kind of things.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look into using AsyncTask. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second attempt, you are making the main thread wait for the new thread to complete.

The runnable in the runOnUiThread call is where you want to do tmp = mc.getStuff();
That will then be executed on the main thread after mc has finished doStuff().

But otherwise, check out the link blindstuff commented, it simplifies threading.